# What would be the properties of an algebra with divisors of infinity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, infinity

What would be the properties of an algebra with divisors of infinity? We have dual numbers where $\epsilon^2=0$ and $\epsilon\ne0$ but what if in our algebra we have $\omega^2=\infty$ yet $\omega\ne\infty$?

Comment: See [projective line over a ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line_over_a_ring). One example is the projective line over the dual numbers, described in the section "Over topological rings". A simpler example would be $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})\mathbb{P}^1$, where $(1/2)^2=\infty$ but $1/2 \neq \infty$.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be more helpful on what you think "infinity" is in an algebra.  Are you saying your algebra is totally ordered and that is a greatest element?  Are you saying it is just some element with a specific property?  Most notions of infinity are not compatible with algebraic operations.